# Typescript: Object is possibly 'undefined' while looping Object.keys()

Tags: typescript, undefined

Give this code:

```js
    interface Test {}
    
    interface Config {
        tests?: Record<string, Test>
    }
    
    const config: Config = {
        tests: {
            'test1': 'test1 implementation',
            'test2': 'test2 implementation'
        }
    }
    
    const readConfig = (config: Config) => {
        const testName = 'test1'
        if (config.tests) {
            console.log(config.tests[testName]);
            Object.keys(config.tests).forEach((name) => {
                console.log(config.tests[name]);
            })
        }
    }
    
    readConfig(config);
```

If I try to access the `config.tests[testName]` immediately in the `if` block then it works fine.
However I'm getting "Object is possibly 'undefined'." on this line, even though I check for undefined above in the `if` condition.:

```js
console.log(config.tests[name]);
```

Comment: You can assert the value is present like so: `console.log(config.tests[name]!);` note the bang ! operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the `tests` into its own identifier first.

```
const readConfig = (config: Config) => {
    const testName = 'test1';
    const { tests } = config;
    if (tests) {
        console.log(tests[testName]);
        Object.keys(tests).forEach((name) => {
            console.log(tests[name]);
        })
    }
}
```

You also might want to use `Object.entries` to get both the key and value at once - or just `Object.values` if you only need the value.

```
Object.entries(tests).forEach((name, value) => {
    console.log(value);
})
```

Comment: `Object.entries(tests).forEach(([name, value]) => {
    console.log(name, value);
})` works best in my case